# Run the same python script with different values over 200 times at once

Tags: python, selenium, worker

Before getting too far, I do not think that multiprocessing or Threading will work in this scenario.

I currently have written a Python worker that sends HTTP Post requests to gather data and when an item comes up that falls within set conditions, this initiates a selenium buyer.  However, this script only functions on a single item and I need to be able to hit over 200 items at once with the same Python script, but with different parameters.

My plan is to create a online database that can be dynamically updated to reflect up to date requested parameters, but need to find a way to apply these values and run on the same script over 200 times at once 24/7.

Comment: Why do you think multiprocessing or Threading will not work here?

Comment: Would it work for this number of items at the same time at the same speeds?  The problem I foresee here would be the amount of computing power necessary, which may be okay if renting processing power, but I would need to hit at the same speeds as well.

Comment: Going with selenium is not a good idea here. Why not hit the API using the request?

Comment: I am able to use requests to get inventory data and add items to a cart, but am unable to send a post request to actually complete the transaction, for this I have to use selenium.  The two processes could be separated once an item is added to the cart, so I just need to find a way to manage several different item inventory price conditions as well as price data for different items and send to the same cart